# Why is CUPS not returning my default printer?

Tags: c++, osx-lion, cups

I'm making the following call:

```
cupsGetDest(0,0,numDests,dests);
```

Where `numDests` and `dests` are set appropriately. `null` is returned, even though I have a default printer set. Why is this?

Comment: What do you get when using `cupsGetDests()`? Anything at all?

Comment: @Bart I am getting a return value of 4 (expected result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was running this as root instead of the desktop user, hence the problem.